# password strength checker python

Tags: python

I wrote a script that checks if the password provided by the future user is correct (one upper and one lowercase letter, one digit and all char are alphanumeric:

```
def check(password):
    word = list(password)
    war = 0
    if len(password) > 8 and len(password) < 24:
        war += 1
    if password.isalnum():
        war += 1
    for x in range ( 0, len(word)):
        if word[x] == word[x].upper() and word[x].isalpha():
            war += 1
            break
    for x in range ( 0, len(word)):
        if word[x] == word[x].lower() and word[x].isalpha():
            war += 1
            break
    for x in range ( 0, len(word)):
        if word[x].isdigit():
            war += 1
            break
    return war == 5
```

and I wonder how to make it shorter and simplier, which python tools, keywords could help ?
Thanks in advance, i'm begginer with python and didn't read the documentation yet

Comment: Working code just seeking 'vague' improvement should be posted on code-review, not here...

Comment: And it looks like you already know the way to go, but are just admitting to being lazy: how about you read some documentation, tutorials?

Comment: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cracklib

Comment: Programming style aside, you should probably read up on suggestions for modern passwords. [This](https://blog.codinghorror.com/password-rules-are-bullshit/) is a good start. Specifically there's no reason to have an upper-bound on password length.

Comment: Some other ideas (regex-based) in [this article](https://www.codespeedy.com/check-the-password-strength-in-python/)

Comment: `if password.isalnum()` doesn't look useful. It marks down passwords with special chars in them. `abc123!'.isalnum() == False`.  And marks up passwords that contain any letter or any number

Answer (score 2):

Your use of a variable "war" to check the strength of the password, and then returning True if it is equal to five is also redundant.

You could have an if statement with a condition for anything that would disqualify the password and return False if any of the conditions are not True. Then you can return True at the end of the function, as this is only executed if no other return statements are run, ie all conditions are True.

For example:

```
if not password.isalnum():
    return False
if len(password) not in range(8, 25):
    return False
...
return True
```

Answer (score 0):

Things like `word = list(password)` followed by `for x in range(0, len(word)):` are really not necessary.  You can just as easily do `for character in password:`, skipping the conversion to list, skipping creating an index, etc.  Comparisons then become things like `if character.isalpha() and character == character.upper():`.  Using zero as the first argument to `range()` is also redundant.  It's definitely worth your time to go over the python tutorials, as all of this is covered very close to the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, instead of converting the password into a list and then iterating over the index of the list, you could just iterate over each character of the password like this-

```
for char in password:
```

Next up since even if a single condition is false then the password is disqualified so it is unnecessary to check all other conditions if the first condition is false.

So instead of updating the `war` variable, you could change the if conditions to something that would disqualify the password and `return False` below it so that you would skip all other conditions if the password is disqualified before. In the end `return True` since this would only run if no other return statements run thus the password is qualified.

code for this-

```
if not password.isalnum():
    return False

if len(password) not in range(8, 25):
    return False

return True
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that there are no checks for sequences like 'abc' or '456' in passwords, nor for dictionary words. You'd probably want to check for those too in order to create a really robust strong password check.

The following is somewhat overkill, but tests that a password has characters of a certain type in the `char_present()` method. It might be of interest because it uses some interesting Python facilities: dictionaries, comprehensions, lazy evaluation and reflection.

You determine the type of char to scan for by passing in one of the following:

- the name of an attribute (e.g. `'islower'` in the expression `'c'.islower()`)
- the name of a separate function (e.g. `'testchar'` in the expression `testchar('c')`)

The attribute or function (`char_present()` figures out which it is) is used to test each character in the password using the `any()` method, which will return `True` as soon as one character is found of the right type.

```py
import os


def strong_password(password, min_length=12):
    print(f"Password '{password}':")
    announce_pass_fail('password length', len(password) >= min_length)
    matchers = dict(
        lowercase='islower',
        uppercase='isupper',
        digits='isdigit',
        specials='special_char',
        # OR specials=special_char,
    )
    results = {
        label: char_present(password, matcher_function)
        for label, matcher_function
        in matchers.items()
    }
    for label, present in results.items():
        announce_pass_fail(label, present)
    if len(password) < min_length:
        return False
    return all(results.values())


def announce_pass_fail(label, present):
    pass_fail = 'passes' if present else '*** fails ***'
    print(f"  - {label}: {pass_fail}")


def special_char(c):
    return c in '!@#$%^&*()-_+='


def char_present(string_to_match, matcher):
    try:
        return attribute_matcher(string_to_match, matcher)
    except (AttributeError, TypeError):
        try:
            return function_matcher(string_to_match, matcher)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            message = [
                f"Don't know what to do with matcher '{matcher}'."
                "It's not a known function or string attribute"
            ]
            raise Exception(os.linesep.join(message))


def attribute_matcher(string_to_match, matcher):
    return any(char.__getattribute__(matcher)() for char in string_to_match)


def function_matcher(string_to_match, matcher):
    # if matcher is a string, convert it to a function object
    matcher = globals().get(matcher, matcher)
    return any(matcher(char) for char in string_to_match)


for password in [
    'password',
    'password1',
    'password!123',
    'slightlyNotGoodEnoughPassword!!',  # no digits
    'biNGo!$94',  # too short
    'strongEnoughPAssword%$9412'
]:
    password_assessment = "strong password" if strong_password(password) else "weak password"
    print(f"Assessment of '{password}': {password_assessment}")
```

Results:

```bash
$ python checkpass.py 
Password 'password':
  - password length: *** fails ***
  - lowercase: passes
  - uppercase: *** fails ***
  - digits: *** fails ***
  - specials: *** fails ***
Assessment of 'password': weak password
Password 'password1':
  - password length: *** fails ***
  - lowercase: passes
  - uppercase: *** fails ***
  - digits: passes
  - specials: *** fails ***
Assessment of 'password1': weak password
Password 'password!123':
  - password length: passes
  - lowercase: passes
  - uppercase: *** fails ***
  - digits: passes
  - specials: passes
Assessment of 'password!123': weak password
Password 'slightlyNotGoodEnoughPassword!!':
  - password length: passes
  - lowercase: passes
  - uppercase: passes
  - digits: *** fails ***
  - specials: passes
Assessment of 'slightlyNotGoodEnoughPassword!!': weak password
Password 'biNGo!$94':
  - password length: *** fails ***
  - lowercase: passes
  - uppercase: passes
  - digits: passes
  - specials: passes
Assessment of 'biNGo!$94': weak password
Password 'strongEnoughPAssword%$9412':
  - password length: passes
  - lowercase: passes
  - uppercase: passes
  - digits: passes
  - specials: passes
Assessment of 'strongEnoughPAssword%$9412': strong password
```

Answer (score 0):

[password-strength](https://pypi.org/project/password-strength/) looks like an interesting Python library that could save you work. It's labelled Production/stable. It has a maintainer but note that its version is 0.0.3 which is a concern. It could be immature and there might be some bugs.

The following is an example taken from its website:

```py
from password_strength import PasswordPolicy

policy = PasswordPolicy.from_names(
    length=8,  # min length: 8
    uppercase=2,  # need min. 2 uppercase letters
    numbers=2,  # need min. 2 digits
    special=2,  # need min. 2 special characters
    nonletters=2,  # need min. 2 non-letter characters (digits, specials, anything)
)

>>> policy.test('ABcd12!')
[Length(8), Special(2)]
>>> policy.test('ABcd12!!1535')
[]
```

If you're a Python beginner, note that you need to `pip install password-strength` before you can use it.

So you can write:

```py
password = ''
while policy.test(password) != []:
    password = input('new password? ')
# process accepted password
```